# RStudio takes too much memory

Tags: windows, memory, rstudio

On my PC as soon as I open up RStudio it takes up an enormous amount of memory. How can I fix it?

I am using a Windows 7 machine with 8 GB or RAM, which is not expandable. I have a 64 bit machine.

I just re-installed RStudio after I noticed my problem. When I look at task manager it says that rstudio.exe *32 is using 137 MB of memory and rsession.exe is using over 2 GB or memory. At this point I have not done anything other than open RStudio. Any ideas?

When I just open Rgui 3.1.2, task manager says I am using 38 MB of memory.

When I open RStudio on my laptop, I get the following.

Rstudio.exe*32 74 MB.
Rsession.exe 33 MB.

On my laptop if I just open Rgui, I get the following.

32 bit R¨20 MB
64 bit R: 29 MB

I do not know if this is related, but if I open up a large number of tabs on Firefox, a large amount of memory is eaten up and it is not returned until I close down Firefox.

On my desktop right after booting up I am using 28% of 8 GB of physical memory and I am running 121 processes.

On my laptop after booting up, I am using 38% of 4 GB of memory and I am running 68 processes.

Comment: The number Task Manager is giving you may not mean what you think it does.  In any case, it looks like you have plenty of memory available on the desktop, so you should be able to spare 2GB for R.  Unless the system becomes unresponsive, there's probably no cause for alarm.

Comment: Please show us output of `gc()` in RStudio.

Comment: probably you open different RProj with RStudio, so all workspace objects are loaded automatically and consume RAM

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   322643  17.3     597831   32.0    418437   22.4
Vcells 97861399 746.7  159412512 1216.3 150940598 1151.6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
In RStudio
> gc()
           used          (Mb)      gc trigger          (Mb)      max used       (Mb)
Ncells   322643    17.3         597831            32.0      418437       22.4
Vcells 97861399   746.7     159412512      1216.3  150940598   1151.6

Comment: used           (Mb)      gc trigger       (Mb)      max used      (Mb)
Ncells   322643       17.3     597831            32.0         418437        22.4
Vcells 97861399    746.7   159412512    1216.3    150940598   1151.6

Comment: On PC
<pre>
            used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells    325007  17.4   14947060  798.3  18017858  962.3
Vcells 114577364 874.2  248183247 1893.5 169313883 1291.8
</pre>

On laptop
<pre>
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 262429 14.1     407500 21.8   350000 18.7
Vcells 473169  3.7     905753  7.0   785973  6.0
</pre>

Comment: I came up with a workaround for my RStudio problem. I uninstalled version 0.99.467 and re-installed version 0.98.932 from June 17, 2014.

So far everything seems to be working well.

Comment: I had the same problem but only that RStudio did not respond anymore. After loading an existing project, everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio Tools Global Options, uncheck all the session saving options. Also clear the environment and run a gc() function

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do anything in RStudio because it froze and it blocked the whole Windows session. So my solution was to delete one very large .rdata file there was in my folder, before opening the RStudio session. 
After deleting that .rdata file, RStudio opened normally again, without freezing because of trying to open that file.